# How can I convert array of arrays to array of objects in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

So I have this code:

```
@app.route("/")
def users():
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        c.execute(''' SELECT * FROM users ''')
        rv = c.fetchall()
        return jsonify(rv)
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

and the output looks like this:

```
[
  [
    1,
    "Robert Soriano",
    "sorianorobertc@gmail.com",
    24
  ],
  [
    2,
    "Charmaine Villar",
    "charmandervillar@hotmail.com\r\n",
    23
  ]
]
```

but since I am doing a restful api, I want it to be in objects like:

```
[
  {
    1,
    "Robert Soriano",
    "sorianorobertc@gmail.com",
    24
  },
  {
    2,
    "Charmaine Villar",
    "charmandervillar@hotmail.com\r\n",
    23
  }
]
```

I tried something like:

```
try:
        c, conn = connection()
        c.execute(''' SELECT * FROM users ''')
        rv = list(c.fetchall()) #converted to list
        return jsonify(rv)
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

But I still get the same output.

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance

Comment: @McGrady thank you. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: `{1,"Robert"}` is a set in Python, not a dictionary, or object (in Javascript), I suppose you want to generate a Json string, Have a look at http://www.json.org/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the db driver you use. I test with `pymysql`. The result of `cursor.fetchall()` and elements in it are all `tuple`. You can use `collections.namedtuple` to assign field name to each element for each record.

```
Record = collections.namedtuple("Record", ["id", "name", "email", "age"])

result = cursor.fetchall()

records = [Record(*record)._asdict() for record in result]
```

There is a excellent tool [Records: SQL for Humans™](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records) has do it for you.